# Add characters to a numeric column in dataframe

Tags: r, replace, addition, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
  V1      V2      V3 
1  1 3423086 3423685 
2  1 3467184 3467723 
3  1 4115236 4115672 
4  1 5202437 5203057 
5  2 7132558 7133089 
6  2 7448688 7449283
```

I want to change the V1 column and add chr before the number. Just like this:

```
  V1      V2      V3 
1  chr1 3423086 3423685 
2  chr1 3467184 3467723 
3  chr1 4115236 4115672 
4  chr1 5202437 5203057 
5  chr2 7132558 7133089 
6  chr2 7448688 7449283
```

Is there a way to do this in R?

Comment: `?paste` (with special attention to the `sep` argument)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The regex pattern "^" (outside any character-class brackets) represents the point just before the first character of a "character"-class item (aka "string" in other computer languages). This just replaces the beginning of each "character" element in vector with a stem of "chr". It implicitly coerces a "numeric" input value to "character" so alters the mode of the result.

```
> dat$V1 <- sub("^", "chr", dat$V1 )
> dat
    V1      V2      V3
1 chr1 3423086 3423685
2 chr1 3467184 3467723
3 chr1 4115236 4115672
4 chr1 5202437 5203057
5 chr2 7132558 7133089
6 chr2 7448688 7449283
```

Could, of course, have used `paste("chr", dat$V1, sep="")`, but I thought a regex solution might be neater.

Comment: What did the sledgehammer say to the nut?  I'll smash you into `paste`.

Comment: If I need to add `chr` in after numbers? ie., `1chr, 2chr, etc.`

Comment: @ah bon `paste(dat$V1, "chr", ...`  would seem to be the obvious modification of the second solution. And `sub("$", "chr", dat$V1)` would be the corresponding modification of the first solution, noting that the pattern '$' in the second suggestion is the regex end-of-string marker rather than the R extraction operator,

Answer (score 7):

sprintf is a lot more powerful than plain concatenation.

```
dat$V1 <- sprintf('chr%i', dat$V1)
```

Comment: I do agree but I don’t use it enough to remember its syntax. Always need to look its parameters which I suppose is not necessarily a bad thing.

Answer (score 4):

We can also use `interaction`:

```
df$V1 <- interaction( "chr", df$V1, sep = "")
df
```

Or using `sqldf`:

```
library(sqldf)    
df$V1 <- as.character(df$V1)
df$V1 <- sqldf("select 'chr'|| V1 as V1 from df")
```

Comment: How do I use interaction on multiple columns? `df[,2:3] <- interaction(df[2:3], "addtext", sep ="")` throws out sort error

Comment: @Vasim `interaction` would only return a single vector (if it would accept a two-column dataframe single argument which I’m not sure about) so I’m quite sure that assignment back to a two column destination would fail.