# Adding character to a column in data frame

Tags: r

Is there a way to add "." at the end of each cell of a column?
something similar to :
[Add characters to a numeric column in dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065097/add-characters-to-a-numeric-column-in-dataframe)
but at the end of the value.

Answer (score 2):

With `paste`, it is easier

```
df1$V1 <- paste0(df1$V1, ".")
```

Or using `sprintf`

```
df1$V1 <- sprintf("%s.", df1$V1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex and `sub` and backreference:

```
a <- c("abc", "dfg", "hij", "xyz")
sub("^(.*)$", "\\1.", a)
[1] "abc." "dfg." "hij." "xyz."
```

Comment: or `sub("$", ".", a)`